# Woocommerce Clear Notices When Adding to Cart

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I call PHP WooCommerce function `wc_clear_notices()` whenever URL `$product->add_to_cart_url()` is called via AJAX?

**PHP**

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="hs_cart vc_col-sm-2">' .
        '<button url="' . $product->add_to_cart_url() . '">Add To Cart</button>' .
    '</div>';
?>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $('.hs_cart button').click(function(){
        $.get($(this).attr('url'));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Code formatting and some spelling